# Как администратору залогиниться от лица пользователя?

Tags: php, авторизация, yii2

Есть сайт построенный на yii2, шаблон advanced. Как из backend реализовать авторизацию во frontend от лица рядового пользователя? Backend и frontend на разных поддоменах. Реализовывал такое как-то давно, не на yii, путем подмены кук, а тут даже не знаю с чего начать, гугление результатов не дало, какие будут годные советы?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое действие назвается "имперсонализация". Для первого Yii есть статья про это:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/154/impersonate-users-within-yii-framework/

Не могу сказать насколько переносимо во вторую версию. Надеюсь сам принцип понятен.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно настроить данные сессий и кук если нужен автовход.

```
// in backend/config/main.php
'user' => [
    'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
    'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    'identityCookie' => [
        'name' => '_backendUser',
        'path'=>'/backend/web'
    ]
],
'session' => [
    'name' => '_backendSessionId',
    'savePath' => __DIR__ . '/../runtime',
],

// in frontend/config/main.php
'user' => [
    'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
    'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    'identityCookie' => [
        'name' => '_frontendUser',
        'path'=>'/frontend/web' 
    ]
],
'session' => [
    'name' => '_frontendSessionId',
    'savePath' => __DIR__ . '/../runtime',
],
```

[Источник](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/686/configuring-different-sessions-for-backend-and-frontend-in-yii-advanced-app/)